# How to properly project a pattern from a spotlight cone?

Tags: texturing, light

I'm trying to project an image onto an object using a spotlight:

[image: Scene]

The image is a somewhat random colour pattern which you can see on the top surface of the rendered cube:

[image: Render]

The problem that I'm facing is that the pattern is not rendered correctly on the two sides of the cube. It looks as if the light rays were projected from above and were just smeared across the sides of the cube ignoring the location of the spotlight.

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Could you upload some screenshots of your setup, or better yet, a blendfile? As it is now, it's hard to say what could be causing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the texture panel for the lamp, go to «Mapping», and change the coordinates from «Global», which seems to be the setting in your case, to «View». This should fix your problem. Works for both procedural and image textures.