# Trying to get a spotlight to project an image in Blender 2.80

Tags: texturing, lighting

I'm new to Blender and I want to project an image on a plane from a spotlight but I'm having difficulty.

This [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/how-to-properly-project-a-pattern-from-a-spotlight-cone) says to find Texture panel for the lamp which I can't find. There is a Texture panel in 2.80 but it doesn't seem connected to the spotlight. I presume these instructions are for 2.79 or earlier.

Can someone direct me to a useful link or at least give a general overview of how to do this in Blender 2.80?

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/127028/30849).

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/correct-vector-input-to-map-texture-light-in-cycles?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62665/avoid-distortions-when-creating-projector-effect

Comment: Explore also the UV project modifier, to have the same effect, but without a light: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html see this related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40651/uv-project-modifier-in-cycles-has-no-effect-what-am-i-doing-wrong/40658#40658

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80007/29586